# NodeJS project works fine on macOS but not on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

After searching a lot on google I could not find the solution of it. I'm making a google chrome extension. And for popup page I'm using ReactJs to build. I have already setup the project in MacOS everything is working fine but when I try to run **npm run build** command in windows it gives the below error:

```
npm-run-all build:*
 bookmarkify@2.0.0 build:contentscript-background
 NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@5.1.6 from typescript
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from E:/Bookmarkify-React/tsconfig.json
Error in bail mode: Error: callback(): The callback was already called.at 
context.callback (E:\Bookmarkify-React\node_modules\loader- 
runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:106:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) Error: 
callback(): The callback was already called.
    at context.callback (E:\Bookmarkify-React\node_modules\loader- 
runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:106:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Note: This command was run via npm module 'win-node-env'
ERROR: "build:contentscript-background" exited with 1.
```

Here is my scripts which are in Package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
"clean": "rm -rf dist && cpy manifest.json dist && cpy src/assets/* dist/assets",
"prebuild": "npm run clean",
"build:contentscript-background": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"build:popup": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false npm run build --prefix src/popup && cd src/popup/build && cpy * /static/* ../../../dist/popup --parents",
"build:options": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false npm run build --prefix src/options && cd src/options/build && cpy * /static/* ../../../dist/options --parents",
"build": "npm-run-all build:*",
"prewatch": "npm run clean",
"watch:contentscript-background": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js -w",
"watch:popup": "npm run watch:build --prefix src/popup",
"watch:options": "npm run watch:build --prefix src/options",
"watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:* build:*",
"zip": "bestzip extension.zip dist/*"
```

},

Here is webpack.config.js

```
    const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { optimize } = require('webpack');
const { join } = require('path');
let prodPlugins = [];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prodPlugins.push(
    new optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
  );
}

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: {
    contentscript: join(__dirname, 'src/contentscript/contentscript.ts'),
    background: join(__dirname, 'src/background/background.ts'),
  },
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?{configFileName: "tsconfig.json"}',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CheckerPlugin(),
    ...prodPlugins,
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
};
```

and here is tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["chrome", "node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["ES2021.String", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["src/background", "src/contentscript"]
}
```

Its very strange the project works well and gets built successfully in MacOS but not in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that some package dependencies differs on Linux and Windows. It might be the case here as well. E.g. the "bcrypt" package differs depending on what OS you're using. So delete the "node_modules" folder and then run "npm install" and it will install the packages correctly for your operating system. I had a similar issue when I tried to copy the entire folder (including "node_modules") to my Linux server. It only worked after removing it and re-installing the packages. Give that a try and let me know if that worked.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply on this. But I want to let you know that I tried removing the node_modules folder and did npm install. the issues is still same.